# Update google worksheet in bulk using gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I am new to working on google sheets using python and gspread so it might be the basic question. I am trying to checking all the phone numbers from google sheet and scan those phone numbers in pipedrive CRM through their API and collecting all the desired info related to that phone number and updating the sheets columns with that info. Problem is the script is taking too much time like 3-4 hours for 400-500 rows so I was looking to optimize it a little if possible may be bulk update or something and I don't know how to perform that with the code I have. Here is my code:

```
import httpx
import gspread
from datetime import datetime
import math

API_TOKEN = "f40227............."

token = {"api_token": API_TOKEN}


stage_statuses = {
    0: "Trying to Contact",
    1: "Took App",
    2: "Rec Docs - Lender Call",
    3: "Financial Sched",
    4: "Compliance Shed",
    5: "Pending Payment",
    6: "PAID",
    7: "Sub'd to Processing",
}


def extract_api_data(phone_number: str):
    info = {}
    info["won/lost"] = ""
    base_url = "https://shc2.pipedrive.com/api/v1/deals?start=0&limit=100&get_summary=1"
    base_response = httpx.get(base_url, params=token, timeout=30)
    total_count = base_response.json()["additional_data"]["summary"]["total_count"]
    total_pages = round(math.ceil(total_count / 100))
    response_data = base_response.json()["data"]
    for p in range(0, total_pages + 1):
        page = p * 100
        url = f"https://shc2.pipedrive.com/api/v1/deals?start={page}&limit=100"
        print(f"Checking Page {url}")
        response = httpx.get(url, params=token, timeout=30)
        response_data = response.json()["data"]
        if response_data is not None:
            for data in response_data:
                phones = [p["value"] for p in data["person_id"]["phone"]]
                for phn_no in phones:
                    if "-" in phn_no:
                        number = phn_no.replace("-", "").strip()
                    elif "+1" in phn_no:
                        number = "".join(phn_no.replace("+1", "").strip().split(" "))
                    elif "Ext" in phn_no:
                        number = phn_no.split(" ")[0]
                    elif " " in phn_no:
                        number = "".join(phn_no.split(" "))
                    else:
                        number = phn_no.strip()

                    if phone_number == number:
                        print(f"Number Matched {number}")
                        person_id = data["person_id"]["value"]
                        info["stage_status"] = stage_statuses[data["stage_order_nr"]]

                        if data["status"] == "won":
                            info["won/lost"] = "WON"
                        if data["status"] == "lost":
                            info["won/lost"] = "LOST"
                        if data["status"] == "open":
                            info["won/lost"] = ""

                        person_url = (
                            f"""https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/persons/{person_id}"""
                        )
                        get_person = httpx.get(person_url, params=token, timeout=30)
                        person_info = get_person.json()["data"]
                        info["benefit_id"] = person_info[
                            "ca8fd59fb797a92665b29c4ee38a45524a6ad51b"
                        ]
                        info["assinged_to"] = person_info["owner_id"]["name"]
                        info["name"] = person_info["name"]
                        try:
                            addr_1 = person_info[
                                "2a556bd22d2c0374f609f6fafcca7949cf9b2ba2"
                            ]
                            addr_2 = person_info[
                                "c003c48faccbde63860456ee2f1a5a50f25529a5"
                            ]
                            addr_3 = person_info[
                                "14d2126d1386f43fdbd18ca803c3faab87315d46"
                            ]
                            addr_4 = person_info[
                                "2d762978f235765bbd5fc547c55beb173c0a7101"
                            ]
                            info["address"] = (
                                addr_1 + " " + addr_2 + " " + addr_3 + " " + addr_4
                            )
                        except:
                            info["address"] = person_info[
                                "2a556bd22d2c0374f609f6fafcca7949cf9b2ba2"
                            ]

                        return info


# authenticate the Google Sheets API
sa = gspread.service_account(filename="crm_creds.json")
sh = sa.open("Form Submissions")

# open the Google Sheet and select the worksheet
sheet = sh.worksheet("Mailers")

# get the phone number column and last update column
phone_numbers = sheet.col_values(2)  # assuming phone numbers are in column B
last_update_col = sheet.find("Last Updated").col
benefit_id_col = sheet.find("Benefit ID").col
stage_status_col = sheet.find("Stage Status").col
won_lost_col = sheet.find("Won/Lost").col
assigned_to_col = sheet.find("Assigned To").col
name_col = sheet.find("Name").col
address_col = sheet.find("Address").col

# iterate through the phone number column and update the corresponding last update cell with today's date
for i in range(2, len(phone_numbers) + 1):  # start from row 2 to exclude header row
    phone_number = phone_numbers[i - 1]
    if phone_number:  # only update if phone number is not empty
        print(f"Checking {phone_number}")
        data = extract_api_data(phone_number)
        now = datetime.now()
        dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        if data:
            sheet.update_cell(i, last_update_col, dt_string)
            sheet.update_cell(i, benefit_id_col, str(data["benefit_id"]))
            sheet.update_cell(i, stage_status_col, data["stage_status"])
            sheet.update_cell(i, won_lost_col, data["won/lost"])
            sheet.update_cell(i, assigned_to_col, data["assinged_to"])
            sheet.update_cell(i, name_col, data["name"])
            sheet.update_cell(i, address_col, data["address"])
        else:
            sheet.update_cell(i, last_update_col, dt_string)
            sheet.update_cell(i, benefit_id_col, "N/A")
            sheet.update_cell(i, stage_status_col, "N/A")
            sheet.update_cell(i, won_lost_col, "N/A")
            sheet.update_cell(i, assigned_to_col, "N/A")
            sheet.update_cell(i, name_col, "N/A")
            sheet.update_cell(i, address_col, "N/A")
```

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I see 2 ways of improvement here:

1. Each call to `sheet.find` will make an API call that will get all the worksheet data then find the pattern init. It can be replaced by a single API call to get all the data and do the searching by yourself.
2. Every time you call `sheet.update_cell` you make an API call. It can be replaced by a single API call that updates the whole row at once, by creating first a list with the values at the right index, then push the new row (if all values are adjacent)

That will save you a lot of time and reduce your reach of the API quota linits.